# the equivalent query of mutual friends in linq or lambda syntax

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, lambda

I have two tables tblFriends and tblUsers where I store user's id and friend's id.
Now I would like to find mutual friends of user1 and user2 in table 'tblFriends' AND details of them e.q. nickname,age ...

```
tblUsers:

Username  nvarchar
Avatar    nvarchar
Age       int


tblFriends:

IdUser1         nvarchar
IdUser2         nvarchar
FriendStatus    int
```

**I find the bellow solution in sql and it works fine but I need the equivalent of this query in LINQ or Lambda**

the solution that I find is here ( https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/280296/query-to-display-mutual-friends )

```sql
SELECT P1.Name
FROM dbo.Friendship AS F1
JOIN dbo.Person AS P1 ON P1.ID = F1.FriendID
WHERE F1.PersonID = 1 AND
      F1.FriendID IN (SELECT F2.FriendID
                      FROM dbo.Friendship AS F2
                      WHERE F2.PersonID = 2)
```

Comment: Did you writing something in Linq? What problem you are facing in that?

Comment: I tried this :  ```Dim query = (
   From f In db.tblFriends Join u In db.tblUsers On u.Username Equals f.IdUser2
   Where (f.IdUser1 = 'John') Select u) ``` But it is not complete of that query in sql

Comment: This may help :

`var frinds  = (from f in db.Friendship 
               where f.PersonID = 2
               Select f.FriendID
              );
    

var query = ( From F1 In db.Friendship 
              Join P1 In db.Person On P1.ID Equals F1.FriendID
     Where F1.PersonID = 1 &&  frinds.Contains(F1.FriendID )
     Select P1.Name
    );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for `Join`:

```
var mutualFriendsNames = db.Users
    .Where(u =>
        db.FriendShips.Any(f => f.FriendId == u.Id && f.UserId == 1) &&
        db.FriendShips.Any(f => f.FriendId == u.Id && f.UserId == 2))
    .Select(p => p.Name);
```

Just notice that this will work only if friendship relation is one way relationship (if user1 is friend with user2 then user2 is not necessary friend with user1).

If the relation is two ways, then you have two options:

1. Define the relationship as two rows in DB (each one describes a way).
2. The relationship is implicitly a two-ways relationship, then you should refactor the LINQ query above:

```
var mutualFriendsNames = db.Users
    .Where(u =>
        db.FriendShips.Any(f => 
            (f.FriendId == u.Id && f.UserId == 1) ||
            (f.FriendId == 1 && f.UserId == u.Id)) &&
        db.FriendShips.Any(f => 
            (f.FriendId == u.Id && f.UserId == 2) ||
            (f.FriendId == 2 && f.UserId == u.Id)))
    .Select(p => p.Name);
```

Comment: thanks for your help , But I got an error in your code:  [link](http://s9.picofile.com/file/8365900700/error.jpg)

Comment: If I want to Join the FriendShips table, how the query should be? I want get some of fields of the FriendShips table in query

Comment: Which friendship relation do you want? I mean there are friendships between mutual friends and person with Id = 1, and friendships between mutual friends and person with Id = 2, which ones do you want?

Comment: the second one (  friendships between mutual friends and person with Id = 2 )

Answer (score 0):

This example is equivalent to the given SQL query

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Friends
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var data = new GenerateExampleData();
            var lstFriendId = (from f in data.lstFriend
                               where f.PersonId == 2
                               select f.FriendId
                              );

            var lstMutualFriend = (from f in data.lstFriend
                                   join p in data.lstPerson on f.FriendId equals p.Id
                        where lstFriendId.Contains(f.FriendId) && f.PersonId == 1
                        select p.Name
                       );
            foreach (var item in lstMutualFriend)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }           
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class GenerateExampleData
    {
        public List<Person> lstPerson;
        public List<Friendship> lstFriend;

        public GenerateExampleData()
        {
            lstPerson = new List<Person>
            {
                new Person
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Name ="Person1"
                },
                new Person
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    Name ="Person2"
                },
                new Person
                {
                    Id = 3,
                    Name ="Person3"
                },
                new Person
                {
                    Id = 4,
                    Name ="Person4"
                },

            };

            lstFriend = new List<Friendship>
            {
                new Friendship
                {
                    PersonId = 1,
                    FriendId = 2
                },

                new Friendship
                {
                    PersonId = 1,
                    FriendId = 4
                },

                new Friendship
                {
                    PersonId = 2,
                    FriendId = 4
                },
            };
        }

    }

    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Friendship
    {
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public int FriendId { get; set; }
    }

}
```